# Can you tell what the mouse says I like to do in my spare time?

Tags: knowledge, rebus

There's something I've been doing a lot lately, and I've finished it multiple times now. Each time is different, which is awesome!

I've decided to create an easy rebus about it.

[image: The mouse is irrelevant.]

**Can you figure out what I like to do in my spare time?**

Comment: Do you level your mustache :P

Comment: _You love mouses_! That's sick. _Mouses_ is not even a word, That's sick too.

Comment: You look at 55 mice. Too easy. And quite a weird hobby.

Comment: "easy" i've been going through stuff and I cant figure it out lol

Comment: I don't think that is a mouse

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Shhh.. Don't tell anyone, okay?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you

> play the videogame Undertale?

The rebus can be read:

> "I love Undertale". "Eye" is a homophone of "I", "lv" is Internet slang for "love" and the images are under the mouse's tail.
> Update: OP tells us that LV or LOVE is short for Level of Violence, a concept used in the game, and that mice are also related the game (I don't know how they are related; perhaps I should play it myself).

"There's something I've been doing a lot lately, and I've finished it multiple times now. Each time is different, which is awesome!"

> The wording fits with the idea of finishing and replaying a videogame.

"Can you figure out what I like to do in my spare time?"

> Playing videogames is something you usually do in your spare time.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer! Both the mice and the Lv (which stands for LOVE, which stands for Level Of Violence) are a play on stuff that happens in said game. It fills you with determination.

Comment: So the mouse is not irrelevant, if his tail was part of the answer

Comment: @frabjrew The fact that it’s a mouse is irrelevant to the answer. I added that to prevent determined puzzlers from focussing on the mouse too much.

Comment: @RickvanOsta: The animal in your picture appears to be a gerbil not a mouse and this makes it confusing

Comment: @James Oops. Well, no one but you spotted that mistake, sorry about that. The animal, whether it's a mouse or a gerbil, wasn't necessary to answer the question, only it's tail was, as is apparent from the accepted answer above. I could've used any animal with a tail, for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

Do you

> Level up.

Maybe Because

> There is an eye, the letters lv(which sound like level), and a mouse that is higher than the eye level, so "I level up"?.

Comment: Good try! But not correct, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You like to do

> high level rebus

First of all because:

> `[![The mouse is irrelevant.][1]][1]
> [...]
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/acd7m.png`

and that's exactly the point that

> take this rebus to an high level

and

> *eye* `/aɪ/` and *high* `/haɪ/` have quite similar pronunciation.

Or you just do

> eye level rebus?

but I would say

> any rebus are based on visual things, or am I missing an adjective before eye?

Comment: Nope. Nice try though!

Answer (score 4):

Are you watching the below during your spare time?

> A CASA DAS SETE MULHERES

Eye Lv could be:

> I love (Eye Lv)

And the picture suggest:

> acd7m.png, which when google, gives me the info

While it said the mouse is irrelevant, I am suspecting there's some relation?

Comment: Nope, not quite. However, the mouse has a relation with the answer, but it isn’t needed to answer the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

You

> listen to modest mouse ([band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modest_Mouse))

Eye

> refers to "I"

Lv

> love

Mouse

> hint that relates to the answer of modest mouse

Extra

> in your [profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42351/rick-van-osta) you say you are a rockstar, in literal terms.

Comment: Haven’t heard of them, thanks for the tip though :)

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer but some thoughts

I'm guessing that

> eye level is a bait. The knowledge tag means we should look for a deeper meaning

We know that

> the mouse is irrelevant, meaning we can discount it completely

The L v

> could mean a number of things. Level, Louis vitton, Las Vegas, low voltage, Latvia, Roman numerals. Level normally is lvl so maybe it's one of the others

The eye

> Idk if there is actually a hidden meaning or if I'm over- thinking all of this, but there are a few attributes that could be important. It's a left eye, blue, it's a woman, blonde hair. It's one eye instead of two

Comment: There is actually a hidden meaning to the Lv. If you know what it stands for, chances are you instantly know the answer. The correct word is not amongst your guesses. Good try!

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a stretch but, Is it (or something related to)

> Sea Life

The eye:

> Sea (See)

Lv:

> Life (Lv corresponding to Live)

The mouse:

> Being the opposite of a Sea animal, the mouse is a land animal

Comment: Nope, sorry! Nice answer though!

Answer (score 3):

IP Block?

I = well, it's an eye!
Lv = Livermorium which is in the p-block of the periodic table

The mouse is only related as a computing accessory.

Comment: certainly the nerdiest of the answers, props!

Answer (score 2):

Have you finished a couple of

> mazes?

Because:

> The rebus can be read as I luv mice, which could be I love maze with an accent? Which also has no mice in the answer, but they have a relationship, as mice are often depicted running around in a maze.

Comment: I’m afraid I’m not that into mazes, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you

> Love Undertale (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertale)

Because that looks like

> I (Eye) Love (abbreviation of Lv) Under a mouse's Tail!

You've finished it multiple times and had different outcomes

> because the decisions you make in the game alter the ending! I want to play this now

Comment: Correct! But beaten by minutes, I’m afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You

> are very sadistic, and enjoy disemvowelling mice

Because

> **Lv** is **Love** with the vowels removed, i.e. disemvowelled.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment, but this is not correct. Also, the mouse seems to be a gerbil, as others have pointed out. (Which was my mistake)